# How do I access files on a c$ resource from C#

Tags: c#

I'm using an example like this:

```
System.IO.File.Copy("\\host\c$\folder\file.end", "c:\file.end", true);
```

But I'm only getting a DirectoryNotFoundException with the description

> Could not find a part of the path '\host\c$\folder\file.end'

What do I have to do to access files on a DRIVE$ resource? I have administrative privileges on the machine.

Comment: Don't forget that if you ever want to run this in another context or give it to another user then it might fail to get the file too.

Comment: Chris, yep. But it's an administrative tool, so admin rights is required. I'll handle it in another context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a verbatim string for the path

```
System.IO.File.Copy(@"\\host\c$\folder\file.end", @"c:\file.end", true);
```

or escape the slashes

```
System.IO.File.Copy("\\\\host\\c$\\folder\\file.end", "c:\\file.end", true);
```

Comment: Wow. I already escaped the slashes (the code sample was free-text), but when using @ it magically worked. What's the difference in using extra \'s and using @?

Comment: @user716748 Read up on verbatim strings on [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: @user716748: the code sample you gave us above doesn't have escaped slashes... And the simple summary of what @ does is it means that only quotes need to be escaped (by doubling up) and every other character is treated literally including line breaks and so on. Its mainly useful (in my opinion) for when writing things like paths which may otherwise become a mess of escapes. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(@"\\host\c$\folder\file.end", @"c:\file.end", true);
```

Because as you can see from exception path is not well formatted. You need to escape `\` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.IO.File.Copy(@"\\host\c$\folder\file.end", @"c:\file.end", true);
```

Force a string literal.